# Windows Server 2019, unable to terminate process: access denied

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, taskmanager, windows-server-2019, taskkill

I mistakenly opened dozens of chrome.exe and chromedriver.exe processes and need to terminate them. I run:

```
Taskkill /IM chrome.exe /F
Taskkill /IM chromedriver.exe /F
```

and killed few. Most of them return: `unable to terminate process: access denied` (translated from italian).

I tried to terminate the single processes with no success, for istance:

```
taskkill /s servername /PID 9512
```

The user I'm logged in with is a "local account" and "Administrator".       I tried to grant the user access via properties, security, users and groups, complete control to the user, nothing.
If I terminate the processes one at a time using task manager it works for most (I get the same error for few), but I really need to kill them all at once without rebooting.